# Node.js http.get in a loop get status codes for all the requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request

When I run a http.get request like this, it returns the status code for 5 entries

```
var http = require("http");

var i = 10;
while (i--) {
    (function (i) {
        http.get("http://localhost", function (res) {

            /*res.on('data', function (data) {
                //console.log( i + "#data# " + data)
            });*/

            console.log(i + " #status# " + res.statusCode);
        });
    })(i);
    console.log("requested " + i);

}
```

But if I add the res.on() event handlers, it shows all the requests.

```
var http = require("http");

var i = 10;
while (i--) {
    (function (i) {
        http.get("http://localhost", function (res) {

            res.on('data', function (data) {
                //console.log( i + "#data# " + data)
            });

            console.log(i + " #status# " + res.statusCode);
        });
    })(i);
    console.log("requested " + i);

}
```

From what I understand - in the first script, I'm not attaching any handlers for any of the res events, so it terminates as soon as the while loop finishes executing. Only 5 calls complete within that time and I get the status codes for them.

My question is if I am only interested in the status code of my requests, is there a way to get them instead of adding handlers for the "res" events?

Comment: You can use node.js ``async`` module for this. ``async.forEach`` is an ideal case for this kind of use case...

Comment: I want to understand what's happening.